# window bat file not working with german umlauts

Tags: java, batch-file, character-encoding

I am creating a .bat file from java program:

```
 final OutputStreamWriter fop = new OutputStreamWriter( new FileOutputStream( "test.bat" ), Charset.forName( "UTF8" ) );
```

and executing it using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec();`
        in directory  (C:\usr\testdir)

```
@echo off
cd C:\usr\testdir
echo "hello"
```

The Above bat file execute successfully.
But When I change the Directory path containing German umlauts it gives me error.`:
The system cannot find the path specified`
where dir path (C:\usr\wÖrkingÄÜÖ) and ./bat will be the same :

```
@echo off
cd C:\usr\wÖrkingÄÜÖ
echo "hello"
```

SO the issue is the path containing umlauts.After Google help I add `chcp 652001` at the top of bat file to change the pageCode but the issue still remain the same . Can any one help me what I am missing??

Comment: Maybe you could try the `Cp1252` encoding instead of `UTF8`.

Comment: tried with :chcp 1252>nul . the error changes to path/to/dir/ is not exexuteable

Comment: Well I meant something like `Charset.forName("Windows-1252")` . http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use `65001`, not `652001`. Try this:

```
CHCP 65001
@echo off
cd C:\usr\wÖrkingÄÜÖ
echo "hello"
```

This should force the batch file to use the UTF-8 character set which should support umlauts.

[image]

Comment: I tried the cmd screen shot. but it was working opposite. WIthout chchp  its cd is working if i run chcp 65001 then its shows active code page but then i was unable to paste/write german umlauts. dnt know why ?

Comment: Did you add it `CHCP 65001` into your batch file and than try it rather than testing it straight into a command prompt?

Comment: Note that this answer is correct if Java uses UTF-8 encoding when writing the file in the example above since codepage 65001 is UTF-8. The programmer can provide the character set to be used via the charset parameter: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html 
For other people that had more luck when they tried codepage 1252, that is probably because their text editor / batch file generation code produced ANSI encoded files. See also Microsoft's documentation of code page identifiers: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/code-page-identifiers

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue and solved it by adding

```
chcp 1252
```

to the CP1252-Encoded batch file.

Comment: I can confirm this solution under Windows 10 Pro with a German keyboard configuration.